# How can I configure the Advanced Consent Mode in Google Tag Manager?

Tags: google-tag-manager

The Google Consent Mode is going to be compulsory in the next year. The Basic or the Advanced Consent modes are going to be the options (depends on the data security officer). The operation of the Basic mode is understood.

I use CookieYes to manage consent settings (the code is not inserted by GTM). How would the measurement look like in GTM? How can I gather cookieless data in that case?

Example:
So, first of all in GTM I enable the Consent Mode (Admin -> Container settings). Then I create a Google Analytics 4 tag with the neccesary trigger. Then because of the enabled Consent Mode, this tag will be fired only when the analytics_storage is granted. Should I create a "(Consent Mode) Google Tags" tag with an Initialization - All pages trigger, with the URL passthrough and Redact Ads Data settings? And if I should, how will be the data forwarded to Google Analytics 4 or Google Ads?

Thank you all in advance,

Comment: Have you tried following their documentation on integrating with GTM?

https://www.cookieyes.com/documentation/features/integrations/implementing-google-consent-mode-using-cookieyes/#Method_1_I_2